# How to change the word "Question" in Moodle's quiz?

Tags: moodle, r-exams

Is it possible to change the word "Question" in Moodle's quiz from the code written in R exams? Sometimes I want to use some other words like "Activity" or "Exercise" instead of "Question".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

`exams2moodle()` does not specify the "Question" label - it only sets the question "name" that is displayed internally when working on the question bank. Moreover, the official documentation of the [Moodle XML format](https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Moodle_XML_format) shows no option for setting this. Thus, R/exams cannot modify this.

Therefore, I think this is part of the language settings of Moodle and cannot be easily edited by the author of a quiz.